# create AMP on Remix

Tags: amp-html, remix.run

The service we build needs to support google AMP(https://developers.google.com/amp). We know that Next.js has built-in support for AMP, but currently, it seems Remix does not support it.
Creating AMP page by page is quite time consuming.
Is there any good way to create AMP for Remix? Any suggestion will be helpful.

- https://remix.run/docs/en/v1
- https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/amp

---

Maintainer of Remix helps.

https://github.com/remix-run/remix/discussions/5225#discussioncomment-4761360

https://sergiodxa.com/articles/use-amp-with-remix

Comment: see here https://sergiodxa.com/articles/use-amp-with-remix

Comment: Link comment above just allow use to choose 1 version, AMP or non-AMP, this is not good enough